# PDE for Wave Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have a boundary value problem

> $u_{tt}$ + $u$ = $u_{xx}$ ; $0$ < $x$ < $\pi$,  $t$ > $0$
>   $u(0, t)$ = $u(\pi, t)$ = $0$
>   $u(x, 0) = 0, u(x, 4) = 0, 0 < x < 2$

I want to find the solution for this BVP using the method of separation of varables. In other BVP problems using the method to solve, their form was like $u_{tt} = u_{xx}$, so I was able to transform them into $X^{''} + \lambda X = 0$ and $T^{''} + \lambda T = 0$ by letting $u(x, t) = X(x)T(t)$. However, in the problem above, we have three terms, $u_{tt}, u, u_{xx}$, so I was not able to solve this problem using the method I suggested. How can I deal with that $u$ in the $u_{tt}$ + $u$ = $u_{xx}$?

Comment: What fails here? The same method still works.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I transformed the equation using the method of separation of variables, and the result was $XT^{''} + XT = X^{''}T = -\lambda$. How can I deal with that $XT$? I want to transform the equation into two $\lambda$ equations like I wrote above, $X^{''} + \lambda X = 0$ and the other for $T$.

Comment: You have it incorrect. Even the original equation without the extra $u$ would fail the way you have written it because you have introduced the $\lambda$ at the wrong time: $$XT'' = X''T = -\lambda$$ The $\lambda$ is supposed to come later, after you have divided everything by $XT$

Comment: @NinadMunshi Then I get $T^{''}/T = X^{''}/X = -\lambda - 1$. Before computing it, can I change $-\lambda - 1$ to $-\lambda ^{'}$ for simplicity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there are functions $T$ and $X$ such that $u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$ for all $t$ and $x$. Then $u_{tt}(x,t) = X(x)T''(t)$ and $u_{xx}(x,t) = X''(x)T(t)$, so the equation $u_{tt} + u = u_{xx}$ becomes
$$
XT'' + XT = X''T.
$$
Dividing this equation by $XT$, we get
$$
\frac{T''}{T} + 1 = \frac{X''}{X}.
$$
Note that the left-hand side is a function of $t$ only whereas the right-hand side is a function of $x$ only. Now $-$ this is the entire point of the separation of variables $-$ the only situation where a function of $t$ can be always equal to a function of $x$ up to a constant is when both functions are constants. Hence, we can introduce here a constant $\lambda$ such that
$$
\frac{T''}{T} + 1 = \frac{X''}{X} = \lambda.
$$
Now the partial differential equation becomes the system of ordinary differential equations
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
X'' - \lambda X = 0, \\
T'' - (\lambda - 1) T = 0,
\end{array} \right.
$$
which can be solved as usual.